# Angular + Python post string and json

Tags: javascript, python, angularjs, json

I have a Python script which sends some events on server. Code looks like this:

```
LOGGER = logging.getLogger("send_event")
POST_EVENT_URL = "http://localhost:3000/event/"

def send(name, data):
   url = POST_EVENT_URL + name
   headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
   auth = None

   r = requests.post(url, auth=auth, data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers, verify=False)

   if (not r.ok) or (200 > r.status_code > 299):
       raise IOError(("Failed to upload session to server. OK %s HTTP        response code: %d" % (r.ok, r.status_code)))
```

I need to pass 2 params to this Python function, one will be string(name) and other is json(data) can someone please help me to figure out how to do this using AngularJS 1? Is it possible at all?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `$http` to send http request. First inject `$http` to controller and implement like this

```
 angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl",function($scope,$http){
    var POST_EVENT_URL = "http://localhost:3000/event/";
    $scope.send  = function(name, data){

        var url = POST_EVENT_URL + name;
        var headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'};

        $http({
            url : url,
            method : "POST",
            headers : headers,
            data : data
        }).then(function(response){
            //success
        },function(resonse){
            //error 
        })

    }
})
```